# Detecting and accessing a usb device from within a webbrowser -i.e using a plugin

Tags: usb, html, detection

Is it possible through a plugin - activeX, Java or Flex to write a brower plugin that is able to detect an read a data stream from a USB device channel.

I have done some research but have not found an answer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832678
http://www.vsj.co.uk/articles/display.asp?id=600

Detect USB drive and his name
http://bytes.com/groups/net-vb/379899-detect-usb-drive-his-name

Can JAVA be leveraged within embedded Javascript to access the USB port?
http://p2p.wrox.com/topic.asp?whichpage=1&TOPIC_ID=70470&#150792
http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=43208d3d
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx?fid=398968&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=76&select=1993811
http://www.icaste.com/jcommusb.htm

Detecting USB Drive Removal in a C# Program
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx

http://www.dotnet247.com/247referenc...32/164968.aspx
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread91049.html

Comment: Can you not write the whole title in capitals, it's not good practice.

Comment: I, too, am looking for a way to access a USB device via a webpage... I so far have found this... http://www.activexperts.com/serial-port-component/howto/html/ Seeing as there are devices to convert RS232 to USB I'm sure there must be a way to do this...

Answer (score 2):

It's considered a security risk to expose local resources and the sandbox environments for the different plugins should deny access to these resources.

So I would say that the answer to your question is a No.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can at least be done with Flash. I use an EasyBloom, a USB gardening diagnostic device. The flash app on their website access the device on my local laptop.

Sadly, I have no idea how they do it since I don't do Flash. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Flash can do it. Your users should allow it first. Check this link:
[Flash documentation for Security](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html)

Comment: Another option is purely relience on InternetExplorer , but I do not recommend that, since it's marke share is dropping and going down all the time ...