# ASP.NET detect usb drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, usb-drive

it is possible to detect usb drive with asp.Net (C#) ?

i know it is possible with windows application, i wonder it work also on WebApplication.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336774/detecting-and-accessing-a-usb-device-from-within-a-webbrowser-i-e-using-a-plugi

Comment: Maybe, but its not recommended. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to detect a USB drive plugged into the client computer or server computer?

Detecting a USB drive plugged into the client computer is impossible, but you should be able to access it just the same if the USB drive is plugged into the server.

Comment: No, not "just the same" there are security restrictions imposed on asp.net code.  You can circumvent this security to still gain access, but it does take extra work.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, ASP.NET code is running on server